# Do I need a visa to go to Canada from America if I have a Green Card?

Tags: usa, visas, canada, borders, niagara-falls

I am planning to *drive* to Niagara Falls to see it from the Canadian side. I have heard good things about seeing it from the other side. So, I want to stay in Toronto for a day, see Niagara Falls and come back.

I have a green card, and, my wife is a citizen from US.

I have read this link, http://www.niagarafallslive.com/niagara_falls_travel_tips.htm, and
this doesn't talk about person with a green card. So, could you advise if I can go to the Canadian side or give me links on this one?  I am on an Indian passport.

EDIT: My experience: We went there at around 7:30 in the morning to avoid the long queue. The border security official asked us to give us our passports, I have given my green card as well with the passport, she asked the purpose of our visit and how many days we were planning to stay. The whole process took around 10 minutes, 7-8 minutes for waiting and 2-3 minutes with the official.

Comment: your edit would be better as an answer, Yoo. Glad you enjoyed Niagara!

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon So, you didn't contact Canadian consulate and didn't have any stamps in your Indian passport before you cross the Canadian board, right? I'm asking because since March 15th 2016 you would need to have Electronic Travel Authorization form. Just wondering do I need anything else apart from it.

Comment: I didn't have to fill out any forms. It looks like ETA is required only if traveling by air. Am I right? 
Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-start.asp (However, lawful permanent residents of the U.S. need an eTA if travelling by air.)

Comment: My mistake, it looks like ETA is required for visiting Canada, regardless of transport mode based on this website: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon your second link also says that eTA is required only for air travel (or "transit" which these days implies air travel). Furthermore, US permanent residents don't need a passport to travel to Canada by land or sea.

Comment: @phoog yes, you are correct. It looks like lawful permanent residents need eTA only if travelling by air.

Comment: I went ahead and put the eTA information in the answer and not the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Then normally, for most people, you would require a visa.  However, keep reading, there is good news, I'm just including all information for future people reading this.

[VisaHQ](http://canada.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-United_States/) - for Indian passport, living in the US, you still need a visa, whether for business, tourist or transit purposes.

[Citizenship and Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) also confirms - visitors to Canada from India require a visa.

The Niagara Falls Live [Travel Tips page](http://www.niagarafallslive.com/niagara_falls_travel_tips.htm) also confirms:

> Persons wishing to travel to Canada whom are not U.S. citizens (ie:
>   foreigner) may be required to get a tourist visa from the Canadian
>   consulate in the country from which they are arriving from. If you are
>   in the USA on a visa and wish to visit Canada while in New York there
>   is a Canadian consulate located in Buffalo New York. **YOU CANNOT OBTAIN
>   A TOURIST VISA AT ANY OF THE BORDER CROSSINGS.** When contacting the
>   Consul, inform them that you wish to obtain a "temporary resident
>   visa". As of April 1st 2012 the fee per person is $75 for a single
>   entry visa, $150 for a multiple entry visa or $400 for a family
>   (multiple or single entry).

**However**, going back to the [Canadian Citizenship and Immigration](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) page:

**Visitor Visa Exemptions**

> Many people do not require a visa to visit Canada. These include:
>
> - persons lawfully admitted to the United States for permanent residence who are in possession of their alien registration card
>     (**Green card**) or can provide other evidence of permanent residence;

so it appears, in fact, that you would be totally fine, as you are in possession of a valid green card!

**Update** - As of 2016, there is a new entry requirement in effect. US Permanent Residents ("Green Card" holders) entering or transiting Canada by air [must be approved](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16) for an [eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-start.asp) (Electronic Travel Authorization) to fly to or transit through Canada unless they are otherwise [exempt](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp#eta-exemptions). This requirement does not apply to those entering by land or sea.

Comment: Nice work Mark!

Comment: Oh good! I can go. Thank you for including links with the information. I will print them and take them as well.

Comment: No worries.  At first it was looking like you'd need a visa, but was very happy when I found the exception on the CIC website. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Sure, will update when I come back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a green card holder you do not need to get a visa to visit Canada. NOTICE if you are get in to Canada and stay more than 6 months, you must apply for a visaa

Comment: Do you have a link or reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

No, and not even a passport: just your Green Card (if entering by **land**. By **air** you'll need a passport with an ETA Registration **and** your Green card)